# how to select two column with same value and ignore column if has parent id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is (sorry my english is bad):

[image]

I want to make category and  under category. For example if record has a parent id , this means category is under category. I want if any record has parent id, show correct.

I test this :

```
select tb1.id,tb1.catname,tb2.id,tb2.catname from adsystem.cat as tb1 inner join adsystem.cat as tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.parentid
```

but output is :

[image]

and test :

```
select tb1.id,tb1.catname,tb2.id,tb2.catname from adsystem.cat as tb1 left join adsystem.cat as tb2 on tb1.id=tb2.parentid
```

this is almost : see

[image]
i dont want to show cat with under red line :

[image]

if output this correct, i can make correct with php

I want to output like this exactly(and this is just photoshop):

[image]

Comment: Why should the display order matter for this? What happens if you end up with more than just 1 layer on child records? e.g. a 3+ deep tree?

Comment: i just want to make 2 level categories . i think if i make seperate categories table and under categories , i can get answer simple

Answer (score 1):

This is what is know as an `Adjacency List`, it would look like you're trying to get a full tree view from your list.

This should be what you're looking for

```
SELECT t1.catname AS lev1, t2.catname as lev2, t3.catname as lev3 FROM adsystem.cat AS t1
LEFT JOIN adsystem.catAS t2 ON t2.parentid = t1.id
LEFT JOIN adsystem.catAS t3 ON t3.parentid = t2.id
```

The `Adjacency List` will work fine for simple fixed data, however if you want a more flexible structure that isn't constrained then I would suggest researching the `Nested Set` model.

**Edit:**

You want the exact output in the last image, this isn't possible with your table schema (well not really possible), there is no correlation to support both (linking / joining) and sorting.  You 'could' do it in a nasty, hacky way which would be slow and really bad idea, you would need to create your own correlation reference at runtime in a new column and then sort by that - either via a string concat or stored procedure.

Why can't you use the normal adjacency list structure, and get the data in a clean way and then manipulate it via application logic?

Comment: thanks for your answer , i test your query and output like my query (pic with under red line)

Comment: I'm sorry but your English is really bad and its hard to understand exactly what you're asking for. My query will allow you to get all children at once. Why do you need that exact output in a database viewer?

Comment: i want this output for make gride for user and ad system, my script just need two level cat , yes my english is bad :(, you just see my last picture of post one , you can undrestand my question prefectly . i test your query , this query show me exactly my query(pic with red line). but i dont want to show under cat in column one

Comment: just see my last picture on post one

Answer (score 1):

I guess this query is needed:

```
select tb1.id, 
    case when tb2.catname is null 
         then tb1.catname 
         else tb2.catname 
    end catname,
    tb1.parentid  
from adsystem.cat as tb1 
left join adsystem.cat as tb2 on tb1.parentid = tb2.id
```

Maybe I understand...

```
select tb1.id cat_id, tb1.catname cat, 
tb2.id subcat_id,   tb2.catname subcat from 
(select distinct id, catname
from adsystem.cat 
where parentid is null or parentid = '') tb1
left join adsystem.cat as tb2 on tb2.parentid = tb1.id
;
```

Comment: test you query but output this(not correct) : http://8pic.ir/images/92569074422097341725.jpg

Comment: your result from photoshop looks like result of this query: select id, catname, parentid from adsystem.cat tb1. Isn't it?

Comment: thanks for your help , i have categorie and under categories , i test your query but not correct order and name . see record with under cat one and under cat two and under cat five

Comment: I try select categories and subcategories, I hope second select will be useful for you

Comment: just see my last picture of post one , you underestand prefectly , i test your query and get me nothnig , see please : http://8pic.ir/images/68553024953224526872.jpg . i want this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/gva80.jpg

Comment: Sorry I've corrected condition for where clause, added  or parentid = ''. Please check it. Which type of your columns id & parentid?

Comment: thanks , yes ,this is exactly i want and your query is correct ;)